# Which way is North in the L5R 2nd edition map?

Tags: l5r, maps, l5r-2e

I've been poring over the various regions and cities in L5R and, though this sounds silly, I'm not sure which way is north anymore. The biggest part of my confusion comes from the GM Guide when describing OOO The Black finger River and the River of the dark moon pg 57. I always figured the Phoenix and Dragon lived in the North and the Mantis isles were to the East...

So which way is north?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, according to information in the Legend of the Burning Sands book for 3rd ed (one of the first concrete references for outside of Rokugan), the Phoenix lands are the northernmost part of Rokugan, but aren't directly in the North.

Take a look at the larger-scale map found [here](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/World/Planet_of_L5R_and_Rokugan) - the Mantis Isles are actually to the south east, the mountains of the phoenix to the north-east, and the Shadowlands to the southwest.

Comment: ok, so I just have to turn my book 90 degrees to see the maps on the front and back covers properly! 
ps: Geee i feel like the kids in "The king and I" when they first see the map of the world and see how small Siam is in comparison xD

Comment: Rokugan might be a thousand years old, but it is certainly not the entire world.

Comment: xD can't find the page where i read it... but at one point I remember reading that Rokugan was used interchangeably to refer to the country and the world ...
King and I anyone?

Answer (score 6):

The Phoenix and Dragon lands are on the Northern border.

This being Rokugan though... the Emperor could declare that the Mantis Isles are in the North, and everybody would have to figure out how to map the truth to reality without admitting to anyone that the Emperor was wrong.

Comment: Although if you take a man-sized section of fourth wall out of the game, you could say that the Mantis are North, putting the Gaijin to the West.